# How to visibly disable past timeslots for Day view jQuery fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is their a configurable way to visibly disable the past timeslots for the current day in the Day view of [jQuery fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)?

I'm displaying business hours 9:00 AM to 6:00 PM for the day. Consider the time now is 12:30 PM, I need to block users to book any events prior to 12:30 PM. Also the disabled timeslots has to be greyed out and unselectable. I can write the select callback validating the time selected. But need a visual effect to let the user feel that the past timeslots are not selectable.

Welcoming custom scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [eventAfterAllRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/)  and append a css class to all slots which have passed.

It should be easy to work out how many rows you need to apply the class to (time of day in minutes / 30). Add the disabled css class to the td's and style with whatever you feel like.

This obviously won't actually disable the slots though and you will need to use the [dayClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) callback to disable past times

Comment: You probably if you want to insure that know one clicks outside that time period 9:00 to 6:00, you will have to make an algorithm to check if the time clicked is inferior or superior, if you know what i mean, and warn the user in case he/her selects outside the time range.
Trying to block throught CSS will be kind of tricky, and its probably a death trap cross browser's...

Good luck

Comment: @HenriqueC. I think the question was just for the visual effect, not blocking clicks. I did mention using the dayClick event to disable clicks, but after rereading the question Babu is using the select event, which is probably more relevant here; within either of these you could use the algorithm you mention

Comment: Indeed tocallaghan, sorry if i misunderstood the question, but nevertheless in both cases, an algorithm must be made :)